# Ag-grid column resize Issue ver@24.1.0 onwards

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Ag-grid column resize
Description --- Able to resize the column, and all column were able fit in screen the other column will automatically get resized to adjust within the viewport we do not get the horizontal scroll bar.

The above works fine in Ag-grid 23.1.0.

But when we uses Ag-grid 24.1.0 the above behavior is not working.

```
jsbin showing the Issue : https://jsbin.com/coreveruru/embed?html,output
```

in above link u can change ver ag-grid-community@23.1.0 >> ag-grid-community@24.1.0

Comment: You can't have both i would say, either you fit in the space, or either it scrolls, you could simply not call the sizeColumnToFit function on mobile

Comment: Agreed, but the same works fine in 23.1.0, My observation is change in code for `sizeColumnsToFit` function triggers this issue. Any quick possibility to achieve it  OR may be in some higher version. As per my findings its not works same as 24.1.0 till latest version i.e 30

Comment: Try to update to the latest version, perhaps that specific version has a bug that was resolved later